# ORA-00933 before update query

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, odp.net

Good day.
I create some repository for objects and try to update same object.
I used 'ExecuteStoreCommand' and next method

```
public void UpdatePatienAccount(long modelId, long patientId, long accountId)
{
//ExecuteStoreCommand(@"UPDATE PATIENT_ACCOUNT SET PATIENT_ID = :1 AND ACCOUNT_ID = :2 WHERE ID == :3", patientId, accountId, modelId);
ExecuteStoreCommand(String.Format("UPDATE PATIENT_ACCOUNT SET PATIENT_ID = {0} AND ACCOUNT_ID = {1} WHERE ID = {2};", patientId, accountId, modelId));            
}
```

And there accrue next exception:

```
"ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"
```

P.S. Parameters of the called method is not zero(not null and not object in not empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENT_ACCOUNT
(
    ID         NUMBER
,   PATIENT_ID NUMBER
,   ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO PATIENT_ACCOUNT VALUES(1, 11, 22);

UPDATE  PATIENT_ACCOUNT
SET     PATIENT_ID = 1
AND     ACCOUNT_ID = 2
WHERE   ID = 3;
-- ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

UPDATE  PATIENT_ACCOUNT
SET     PATIENT_ID = 33
,       ACCOUNT_ID = 44
WHERE   ID = 1;
-- 1 rows updated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional the semicolon (;) at the end of the statement is incorrect. Even in a "execute immediate" command you have not to use the semicolon.